# Error Checking in Excel

Tags: excel, excel-formula, conditional-formatting

I've got a workbook, that i use for fleet allocations, but i'm not sure how to do error checking in excel, and was wondering if anyone could point me in the right direction. When i allocate the vehicles to a duty, it uses vlookup to bring the driver name into the sheet. but what im unsure of how to do is, i have 54 duties, and it would be easy to miss one, so is there a way i can make it show me which duties are left to allocate ? please see screenshot...

[Excel Worksheet Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Feh5N.jpg)

Comment: Its not always the same vehicle on each duty. I just want to know how to get it check the duty column against a list of duties that haven't been entered?

Answer (score 0):

For a layout as shown:

[image: SO5067083 example]

Select ColumnA, clear any existing CF from it and HOME > Styles - Conditional Formatting, New Rule..., *Use a formula to determine which cells to format* and **Format values where this formula is true:**:

```
=AND(A1<>"",COUNTIF(C:E,A1)=0)
```

<kbd>Format...</kbd>, select formatting of choice (I chose the same fill as for the headers)  <kbd>OK</kbd>, <kbd>OK</kbd>.

Answer (score 0):

Well, had a look at your sheet... But I put this together as it is simple and you may be able to include it where you can...

Tha match() function looks for the duty in cell A2 and if it finds it in the list in column I then it returns its position number. If not found the iferror() returns "Not Allocated"...

The formula in cell B2 is:

```
﻿IFERROR(MATCH(A2,J$2:J$10,0),"Not Allocated")
```

[image]